# Translating Stata if else statement to python

Tags: python, python-3.x, stata

I have this piece of
Stata code that I am trying to translate into python.

```
if inlist(nid, 4580, 4250, 165101, 4679, 236205, 419098, 438439, 11240, 317089, 430032, 3716, 164729) {
    capture confirm variable child_age_year
    if !_rc {
        replace child_age_year = 0
        }
    else {
        gen child_age_year = 0
        }
}
```

It is supposed to create a age_year variable for surveys that have no child_demographics.

What I have now is the translation of the first 2 lines like so:

```
if sum((df['nid'] == i).any() for i in [4580, 4250, 165101, 4679, 236205, 419098, 438439, 11240, 317089, 430032, 3716, 164729]) == 12:
```

How should I finish the statement so that it replicates the original Stata code?

Comment: I don't know Python but I am guessing that you're translating the `inlist()` call as that all numeric values are present,  but it means only that at least one value is present, and as it applies only to the first observation, two or more values cannot be present.  The only possibilities are zero or one.

Answer (score 1):

The code does not make much sense in Stata.

What doesn't make sense is that the over-arching command

```
if inlist(nid, 4580, 4250, 165101, 4679, 236205, 419098, 438439, 11240, 317089, 430032, 3716, 164729)
```

can in Stata only apply to the first observation (case, record, row) in the dataset.

In other words. it means in practice

```
if inlist(nid[1], 4580, 4250, 165101, 4679, 236205, 419098, 438439, 11240, 317089, 430032, 3716, 164729)
```

as a condition attaching to the rest of the code.

The rest of the code says: if such and such a variable exists, overwrite its value with 0 in every observation; otherwise create it with 0 in every observation.

What is perhaps more likely is  the original programmer was confusing the `if` command (used here) and the `if` qualifier.

I'd put a prior probability near 1 on this code and whatever it comes with as being not worth translation until it is checked.

Comment: I spoke with the original creator of the code and got it clarified with him. He wanted the if command to trigger if any of those nid values were present in the data frame and simply generate a column called child_age_year and set them all to 0.

I ended up creating a solution with his help and I'll update the post with it.

Comment: .... so long as he appreciates that Stata only looks in the first observation (row, record, case). Also, as said your Python code doesn't strike me as obviously a one-to-one translation.

Answer (score 0):

I spoke with the original creator. He wanted to have the if statement run if any of those "nid" values were present and create a column called child_age_year and have it set to 0.

In python it looks like this:

```
if ([4580, 4250, 165101, 4679, 236205, 419098, 438439, 11240, 317089, 430032, 3716, 164729] in df['nid'].values).any():
            df['child_age_year'] = 0
```